Tuple and types narrowing
Could somebody help me to understand the following situation:
export function functionThatReturnsTurpleObjects():
  | [{ a: number }, undefined]
  | [undefined, { a: number }]
 {
  if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
    return [undefined, { a: 1 }];
  }
  return [{ a: 1 }, undefined];
}

function execute1() {
  const [res1, res2] = functionThatReturnsTurpleObjects();
  if (res2) {
    return res2;
  }
  // res1 can't be undefined and ts understand it
  res1.a;
}


function functionThatReturnsTurpleObjectAndString():
  | [{ a: number }, undefined]
  | [undefined, string] {
  if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
    return [undefined, "1"];
  }
  return [{ a: 1 }, undefined];
}

function execute2() {
  const [res1, res2] = functionThatReturnsTurpleObjectAndString();
  if (res2) {
    return res2;
  }
  // res1 can't be undefined but ts throws error "TS18048: res1 is possibly undefined"
  res1.a;
}

Playground
I would expect that both cases should work in the same way.

You'll have to check whether res2 !== undefined explicitly. A truthy check won't work here because a string may be defined but empty  (=""). See this playground. Does that address your question? If so, I'll be happy to write up an answer.

Yeah, now its clear, thanks a lot.

The difference between your first and second example lies in the return types of your functions.

Example 1 returns [{ a: number }, undefined] | [undefined, { a: number }]
Example 2 returns: [{ a: number }, undefined] | [undefined, string]

Now, your trying to narrow the first tuple item (index 0) based on the value of the second item (index 1). This kind of control flow analysis for destructured discriminated unions was implemented in microsoft/TypeScript#46266 and introduced in TypeScript 4.6.
The narrowing in example 1 works fine since checking for a truthy value (if(res2)...) clearly distinguishes { a: number } from undefined. Or in other words, a value assignable to { a: number } cannot be falsy.
However, an empty string (="") is equal to undefined in a boolean context because both values are coerced to false. In order to prevent this you can use a more specific if-condition, such as res !== undefined.
function execute2() {
  const [res1, res2] = functionThatReturnsTurpleObjectAndString();
  if (res2 !== undefined) {
    return res2;
  }

  return res1.a;
  //     ^? const res1: {a: number; }
}

TypeScript Playground
